# I can't redirect user after login

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, redirect

I have login page which take username and password from user after user will be login. I am getting response for successfully login. but I can not redirect to `index.php`.

I am getting console message that User successfully login, But then page is not redirect on other page.

My `JS` file is like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('ss');
 $("#login-form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   
  var username = $("#email").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var isValid = true;
  var re =  /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
 
  if(!re.test($("#email").val())){
   isValid = false;
   $("#message").html("Please enter valid email.");
  }
  
  if($('#remember').is(':checked')){
   $.cookie('adminCookie', $("#loginUser").val(), { expires: 7 });
  }
  else{
   if($.cookie('adminCookie') == null) { 
    $.removeCookie("adminCookie");
   } 
  }
  if(password == ""){
   isValid = false;
   $("#message").html("Please enter password.");
  }
   
  if(isValid){
   
   $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "process/login.php?rand="+Math.random(),
    data : {
      username : $("#email").val(),
      password : $("#password").val(),
     }
   }).
   done(function(response){
                //alert(response);
    var JSONArray = $.parseJSON(rawJSON);

    console.log(response);
    if(jsonObj.success=="1"){
                    
                    window.location("index.php");
    }else{
     $("#userDiv").addClass("form-group has-error");
     $("#passDiv").addClass("form-group has-error");
     $("#passWarning").css("display","");
     $("#passWarning").html("Invalid User Name or Password");
     $.when($('#passWarning').fadeOut(5000)).done(function() {
      $("#userDiv").attr('class', 'form-group');
      $("#passDiv").attr('class', 'form-group');
     });
    }
   }).fail(function(){
     
   }).always(function() {
     
   }); 
  }
 });
});
```

my `PHP` file is looks like this.

```html
<?php
include "../connection.php";
extract($_POST);
$data = array();
$resArr = array();
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $check_user = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from cut_users where email like '$username' and password like '$password' and user_role like 'A'");
    if ($check_user) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($check_user) > 0) {
            $message = "Login successfully.";
            $success = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_user)) {
                if ($row['is_active'] == "0") {
                    $message = "Your account is blocked. Please contact admin.";
                    $success = 0;
                }
                $data["id"] = $row['cut_users_id'];
                $data["name"] = $row['name'];
                $data["emailID"] = $row['email'];
                $data["device"] = $row['device_type'];
                $data["is_reset"] = $row['is_reset'];
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['cut_users_id'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
                $_SESSION['emailID'] = $row['email'];
            }
            $resArr = array("success" => $success, "data" => $data, "message" => $message);
            
        } else {
            $resArr = array("success" => 0, "data" => array(), "message" => "Email or password invalid.");
        }
    } else {
        $resArr = array("success" => 0, "data" => array(), "message" => "Something went wrong!!!" . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
} else {
    $resArr = array("success" => 0, "data" => array(), "message" => "Parameter Missing");
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo str_replace("\/", "/", json_encode($resArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
?>
```

Comment: Where is `jsonObj` defined for the test if the user has logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Why you are using variable `jsonObj` instead of `response` ?

2) Modify your `if statement` like this

```
if(response.success==1){
     window.location.href="index.php";
}
```

Comment: still not working. It just print `{"success":1,"data":{"id":"307","name":"admin","emailID":"admin@admin.com","device":null,"is_reset":"N"},"message":"Login successfully."}`

Comment: Show me console.log(response); output

Comment: If you are getting response like `{"success":1,"data":{"id":"307","name":"admin","emailID":"admin@admin.com","device":null,"is_reset":"N"},"message":"Login successfully."} `  it should work

Comment: Thanks its working i need to comment `var JSONArray = $.parseJSON(response);`

Answer (score 1):

window.location is not a function it is an object. Please change href property in window.location object to redirect to new url.

```
window.location.href = "./index.php";
```

Comment: thanks its working I need to comment `var JSONArray = $.parseJSON(response);`

Answer (score 0):

Simple redirect to specific file

```
if(jsonObj.success==1)
{
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/index.php";

}
```